# jekyll 3.9.0 | Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb:502:in `read': no implicit

Tags: jekyll, bundle

after update to Ubuntu 22.04 I am failing with Jekyll.

`bundle exec jekyll serve` creates this error:

```
...
                  done in 8.248 seconds.
jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb:502:in `read': no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer (TypeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/pathutil-0.16.2/lib/pathutil.rb:502:in `read'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils/platforms.rb:75:in `proc_version'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils/platforms.rb:40:in `bash_on_windows?'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:77:in `watch'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:43:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
...
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

Any advice how to fix this?

jekyll repo: https://github.com/schmidb/TurtleTrafo

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 3 may be the problem, see:

- https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/error-no-implicit-conversion-of-hash-into-integer/5890/7
- https://github.com/envygeeks/pathutil/issues/4

The second link suggests downgrading to Ruby/Bundler 2.7

There is another interesting info in this thread:

> on 26 Apr
> Jekyll v3.9.2 finally removed Jekyll's main dependency on pathutil. Now that Github Pages updated to that version of Jekyll (see https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/833), this issue shouldn't affect Github pages or Jekyll anymore.

Your Gemfile.lock says Jekyll 3.9.2 so the issue should be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed for me after updating the `github-pages` gem:

```bash
bundle update github-pages
```

The above assumes Bundler is installed (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll#updating-the-github-pages-gem)).